# Measure Performance of Hyperledger Fabric Project

Tags: java, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm developing a Blockchain project using as "template" this project: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk

I want to measure the time it takes to query a transaction depending on the amount of transactions in my network.
How can I do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen Caliper? https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/caliper and this tutorial: https://medium.com/@nima.afraz/hyperledger-caliper-explained-and-installation-guide-ubuntu-c38dc16d3dcf

Comment: You can use jmeter to send any number of transactions in a second to hit apis.

Comment: @RThatcher how can I use caliper integrated with the project mentioned. I'm using Eclipse as IDE and then this fabcar project